# How can I call a CMS Block in a product view page under a individual manufacturer In magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to show a promotional banner in all product detail page of a  particular  Brand
Example: Suppose we have Nike , Adidas And puma shoes in a store,
Now i want a  show banner of a **Nike**  in all  individual **Nike shoes product detail  pages**  ONLY not in adidas or puma

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

***Quick and dirty*** - add this to your `app/design/frontend/<your_theme>/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml` in the place you want the banner to be displayed:

```
<?php if ($_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer') == "Nike"): ?>
   <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('<cms_block_identifier>')->toHtml());?>
<?php endif;?>
```

just replace the placeholders with the appropriate values which apply in your case.

Comment: thank you  so much:)
problem i am facing  
1)In futere suppose i have to run a promo in different  brand i have to each time edit  the php code to change of identifier and brand name , is there a way i can amke it dynamic.?

2) i have made e a little change to show image

 <?php if ($_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer') == "Good Health"): ?>
   <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('product_promo')->toHtml();?>
<?php endif;?>

i discarded escapeHtml

Comment: 1. Of course, you can make it more dynamic. My suggestion - add a simple admin config where you add a string as value, say 'adidas'. In your product view file or in a custom block, validate that the current product manufacturer equals to your configuration value if so, make it load the cms block where as a convention you define the block to contain the configuration value in its identifier. 2. It's all good.

Comment: ok will try and let you know, thank you for your kind help

Comment: You are most welcome!